# error when creating custom array adapter in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, listview, android-arrayadapter

I allready created some custom array adapters and they all work. I created this one like the other ones but I keep getting this error:

"android.view.InflateException:  can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true"

My Array Adapter:

```
class CustomArrayAdapter(private val context: Activity, private val customList : ArrayList<Component>)
: ArrayAdapter<Component>(context, R.layout.customcardcomponent, customList) {

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customcardcomponent, parent, false)

    val description: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.Description)
    val progressText : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBarText)
    val progressBar : LinearProgressIndicator = view.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar)

    description.text = customList[position].description
    progressText.text = "${customList[position].current}/${customList[position].max}"
    progressBar.max = customList[position].max
    progressBar.progress = customList[position].current

    return view
    }
}
```

My ListViewPage.kt File

```
class ListViewPage : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false)
    val customListView = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.customListView)

    val listDescriptions = arrayOf(
        "description 1",
        "description 2",
        "description 3",
        "description 4",
    )
    val listMax = arrayOf(5, 10, 25, 50)
    val listCurrent = arrayOf(current, current, current, current)

    val customList : ArrayList<Component> = ArrayList()
    for (i in listDescriptions.indices){
        val component = Component(listMax[i], listCurrent[i] ,listDescriptions[i])
        customList.add(component)
        if (customList.size == 4){
            customListView.adapter = CustomArrayAdapter(context as Activity, customList)
        }
    }

    return view
    }
}
```

My ListViewPage.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/customListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

In the ArrayAdapter I tried to:

change
{LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customcardcomponent, parent, false)}

to
{LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customcardcomponent, parent, true)}

But the I get the follwoing error:
"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView"

I also tried to create a whole custom class for this list view, but I still got the same error.

I would like to know what Iam doing wrong with this ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Here is the line form your fragment you should look into it :

```
  customListView.adapter = CustomArrayAdapter(context as Activity, customList)
```

you can't treat your fragment as an activity

if you want to refer to your fragment context you may want to use `requireContext()` or `requireActivity()` instead if (context as Activity )

and you also you may want to change your adapter's class first parameter from activity to Fragment or yourFragmentName specifically